# Image in center and behind a background gradient

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create a row for a front page (like a slider) with an image where there is a man and behind him is a gradient.
the image is as it is, centered in container (width 1170px) and that works fine but i need to make a row behind the image to go full 100% for larger resolutions. I am using bootstrap 3.

The way I see it, the background 'row' div should have a dark color from left to center, and from center white color should go to the right. 
I dont believe a gradient on row should work because of the resizing hm?
I cant find any similar websites that have this. 
Is there a better solution?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="container"  id="slider">
            </div> 
        </div>
</div>

#slider {
    background: url('image.jpg');
    height: 550px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of Design normally we **remove** left portion **if it's not necessary**. Otherwise we need to make **display block both div left and right**.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Which left portion is removed? I dont have any divs on left and right, how would I insert them? Do you know some similar examples so I can take a look? Thank you :)

Comment: Please check http://sooryen.com/ and Agile Engineering section.
It's look different in desktop and mobile view